# Code Review is in need of a new moderator

Tags: discussion, status-completed, beta-progress, moderators

I know that we are a beta site, but from the looks of it, they only choose [moderator pro-tems](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) 2 weeks into a beta site.  I think we need to follow the path set forth for nomination of a new moderator, if nothing else to show that we are a growing site and have enough active users to become a full SE Site.

This post was inspired by this post: [Winston Ewert is no longer a moderator?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/900/winston-ewert-is-no-longer-a-moderator)

**So let's nominate some moderators**

Moderators should be members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

**Self nominations are okay and encouraged**

Each nomination should be a separate answer to this post.  In the answer, please specify:

- link to Code Review and Meta profile
- links to other activities may be helpful

Please keep in mind if the nomination is posted by a 3rd-party, the nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer and adding that they accept the nomination.  Optionally, they can write something about themselves.

**Additional Information**

I just saw a post here on Meta about when they chose the pro-tems the [first time](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) and it looks like they actually had **4** moderators to start with.

*We are currently at two moderators*: one in Australia and one in Germany.

I haven't really noticed anything not happening quickly and efficiently, but this may be something that we would bring up as well.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think nominations will be sufficient at this time.  Since we haven't graduated yet, we cannot elect moderators ourselves.  SE has to appoint them.  I'm not sure when this will be done, though.

Comment: from what I read in that link, it looks like we can still nominate who we think should be a moderator but they would choose. I flagged this question like the post said as well so they are aware of this thread.  I know we can't independently hold an election, but I think we can let SE know that we need another moderator (they probably already know) and that we think certain people are ready for the responsibility.

Comment: Alright.  I'll post something in a bit.

Comment: we need some more action on this post.   are we the only people that are active on the Meta Site?

Comment: @Malachi: This post is already "stickied" on the main page, which does help a bit.  Other than that, not too many people participate on Meta overall.  But there is still decent voting for that level of activity.  Also keep in mind that SE still decides the outcome, and you never know if either of us are chosen.  The community cannot sway their decision directly pre-election.

Comment: I hear what you are saying.  what do you mean "stickied" on the main page?

Comment: I meant that it's on the Community Bulletin.  I was thinking about forum terminology for some reason. :-P

Comment: Ah, right.  I do remember there being a fourth.  However, it seems to me that we were at three mods for a while, which possibly indicates that SE believes we just need three.  As for the current ones, I *suppose* there are some time zone factors here when choosing a mod.  Winston Ewert is located in Waco, TX, which is only a few hours from my current location.  So, we're obviously in the same time zone.

Comment: I think that I too am in the same Time-Zone as you are @Jamal.

Comment: I believe you are correct.  I haven't looked into it at all, but I would think that having mods from different time zones will ensure minimal periods of time of no mod surveillance.

Comment: Post is 9 Days Old, the community has spoken!!!  should I re-flag this post???

Comment: No, not yet.  SE hasn't made a decision, but I do hope they found this post.

Comment: I think that it fits perfectly, we only have 2 Moderators at the moment, and we are requesting another. :)  Now we just have to wait, it's been a couple of weeks now since we noticed that we only had 2 Moderators.

Comment: just for the sake of the information, CodeSparkle has edit one of the questions that I linked to so that it only shows the two active Moderators, I think that it was necessary so that people didn't think there were more moderators.

Comment: Hi, Code Review! You guys like Jamal, eh? Well, we at the team agree! [Please welcome him as your newest pro tem moderator](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/please-welcome-your-newest-pro-tem-moderator)!

Comment: We have just written a page in the history of StackExchange beta-status sites - we've held our first successful election!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*gulps*

Well, hello there everyone.  I would like to nominate myself for the moderator position.  Although I haven't yet been here for a year, I feel that I've accomplished so much in terms of keeping this site clean and helpful to others.  Although I certainly don't need to be a moderator to keep doing what I'm doing, I know I can do more (or technically less, being a flesh-and-bone exception-handler) with this position.

***Why do I want to be a moderator?***

Needless to say, we're still in beta, meaning that everything is still being tested.  Fortunately, like software, there's always room for improvement.  However, we're maintained by <s>evil overlords</s> a friendly team of developers, and we can be shut down if we stop growing.  And this is where I feel a strong moderator team is important.  Not only to do the dirty work, but to keep the community together because, after all, [Stack Exchange is <s>me</s> us](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). :-)

But enough talk.  *Why do I want to be moderator?*  Ever since I discovered this place, it's been one of my favorite places to <s>kill time</s> improve my knowledge.  But, over time, I've felt that that's not the only thing I want.  I also want to help *others*, as I've being doing by answering questions and improving posts.  Although moderation is more than just that, I believe moderation is just another way to help others, just as this place has helped me and will continue to help me.

***Do I have what it takes?***

Well, that's a tough one.  I've never really moderated a site before, although obviously I'll be with other moderators.  I can only promote myself based on my accomplishments in these past eight months on SE:

*Code Review*:

- My highest rep privilege is moderator tools, which... has the word "moderator" in it

  - I use it frequently to address flags
  - I also use it to find additional questions that need a close or delete vote
- I was the *second* user here to have earned the Deputy and Copy Editor badges
- I have earned nearly all of the moderation badges, including Convention
- I vote (up, down, close, reopen) frequently and carefully, which I know is *essential*

  - I also have the Electorate badge
- I suggest/edit posts as I see fit, even if minor (but necessary) tweaks are needed
- I help others improve their assistance by reviewing edits, also to help them earn rep

*SO, MSO, and Arqade*:

- I frequently suggest edits and have a high acceptance rate

  - I have the Strunk & White badge on SO
- I have the Deputy badge on all of these sites

  - I have the Marshal badge on SO and Arqade
- I have the Electorate badge on SO and MSO

*Overall*:

- I check these sites regularly and do what I can to help
- I'm <s>addicted</s> around quite often, which is essential for very active sites
- I f*** hate spam and will flag it as such in a heartbeat
- But I'm okay with it in meat form
- I like waffles and unicorns, too
- I have a <s>sick obsession</s> delight seeing poor and helpless tags burn
- Um

Comment: If you hadn't nominated yourself, I would have nominated you! You're just about everywhere, you're always respectful in every single post of yours that I've seen, you've got a sense of humor and you're more than just obviously addicted to this site. I'm sure you'd do great with the almighty moderator powers and wouldn't suddenly turn into an *evil overlord j@ck#$$* with an inflated head. Wow this almost feels like an election page.. I hope it gets *some* attention from SE :)

Comment: @retailcoder: Thanks. :-) As Malachi said, the original post has already been flagged.  I'm entirely new to this whole process, so I don't know what will happen.  SE *may* take these into consideration, but the community still cannot directly decide.  I also don't think they will consider votes because, technically, anyone can vote for more than one person (or even downvote someone).

Comment: Thank you immensely for your dedicated contributions to the site. I do have a concern, though: if elected as moderator, would you yield to other users to take a more active role? According to A Theory of Moderation, moderators should do "as little as possible" and "guide the community with gentle — yet firm — intervention", or as I would put it, serve as a resource for sober second thought. Your thoughts?

Comment: @200_success: I'm very glad you've brought that up.  In fact, I am absolutely okay with doing this, and I *know* it's necessary.  What I plan on doing is continuing to observe the community to see what everyone does and does not do.  For instance, we're very good about closing posts, so no problems there.  But, we also don't have enough 2K+ users casting delete votes, so I *may* take action there.  But for the most part, I'll sit back and wait for flags to be raised.  I also already observe what the SO mods do.

Comment: @200_success: On the other hand, I'll continue answering questions as usual.  That's not related to moderation.  But, I do hope there won't be any voting bias when I post answers-- I'm not as smart as the higher-rep users here.  As for editing posts, I could still certainly step back, even though direct-editing doesn't change with moderators.  I would still let the 1K+ users review edits, and I'll be around if there are any concerns (spammers, sock-puppets, etc).

Comment: I just noticed this post was marked as the accepted answer. Does it mean we've reached consensus with < 10 votes?

Comment: @retailcoder: I'm not sure.  The OP has just decided to accept it, which I assume means that I've won (although SE still hasn't decided, while it could be anyone).  I really wanted to see more entries, seeing as there must surely be more people willing to take the position.

Comment: *The OP* gave you his vote (and the +1 on Malachi's is also mine, poor guy was getting washed!), and I just noticed you also have a -1 here (just hit 750 recently!)... I wonder what the participation rate of an actual election would turn out to be..

Comment: That is very nice of him, and I've given my vote as well.  Normally voting for "opponents" wouldn't happen in an election, but this isn't official anyway.  Overall, I'm trying to sell myself to both SE and the community, though obviously SE already has access to all of my activity.  As for the -1, clearly someone doesn't agree with me being a mod here.  That's quite alright, and I cannot expect everyone to want me in this position.  But if I do get it, I will strive to remain as fair as possible.

Comment: @retailcoder I just figured that the more answers there were on this post the more attention it would get. and I am fairly addicted to this site.

Comment: Good call! To be honest I'm addicted as well, just this morning, 5:35AM alarm rings (on cell phone), I turn it off, and hit the "Internet" shortcut, takes me to CR, refresh, see if suggested edits were approved (yay! 40 approved, 0 rejected!) and if last answer got any upvotes. Get up. In that order. Repeat everyday, and then at work, frantically check in every 5 minutes or so, to see if there's something interesting I could review when I get home.

Comment: @retailcoder: I *think* this may also be a reason why I'm less-productive in my classes this semester.  I'm *this* close to having CR as my homepage.

Comment: @retailcoder: You're half-way to Strunk & White! :D

Comment: @Malachi I don't need it as a home page, I just right-click my pinned browser and click that pinned *Code Review* shortcut :) Jamal: is there anything like a "Flawless Victory" badge (ref.MK) for getting S&W without a single rejected edit?

Comment: @retailcoder: Nope, but that would be awesome.  I almost went without a reject on Arqade, though.

Comment: I very Rarely close the tab with CR in it. it is up all the time, and I too am checking CR constantly, along with SO.  I miss some weekend days though, so I won't get the badge for 100 days in a row.

Comment: Congrats on the diamond!

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Thanks!  I will wear it proudly.

Answer (score 11):

I don't have a very high Rep Score here or on any of the SE Sites but I think that I have a good knowledge of what goes where, and how this democracy should work.

I also am willing to learn more as I go along.

I am active in the site and will continue to be active.

I like reviewing code and having my own code reviewed while I am waiting for queries to run or code to compile, or when one of Microsoft's many applications decides it wants to be slow.

I don't think that I have done as much as Jamal for this site yet, but feel that I have something to work up to.

I am slow to Anger and Quick to listen and understand, I also am quick to admit when I am wrong and rephrase my words when I am misunderstood or say something that is ambiguous.

I am active on Several SE Sites
Top 5

- Stackoverflow
- Christianity
- Programmers
- SuperUser
- CodeReview

My vote is for Jamal though.

Comment: I do agree that you have adequate qualifications, especially at this point.  Rep does have a key role, but I don't think you're expected to have a lot.  I do value your willingness to suggest edits, which is something not too many people are doing (though I'm afraid that could be due to my excessive editing).  You're doing different things to help the site, and I value that.  CR needs more willing people to help this site grow, and not just by answering questions.  And you posting here certainly puts your name out there.

Comment: thank you @Jamal. I got internet back and will be learning another language or more this winter, so hopefully I will be able to add more to the answer base as well

Comment: I will eventually learn Java in school, though it'll be a while before I'll be able to answer Java questions.  Just like with C++, I would just start with asking questions.

Comment: I am actually starting to learn Javascript rather than just winging it when I have to deal with it. so that should be fun.  after that I will have to pick a language, thinking either Ruby, Python, PHP or More Arduino

Comment: @Jamal Don't worry about the Java questions, I will help with those :) I've only been here for 10 days now (although I already feel like a regular) but both of you have my support for becoming moderators, and I do hope that SE will take this post in consideration.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Thanks. :-) They have actually considered it, as it has been mentioned in Grace Note's review.  And as a matter of fact, I have recently received an email regarding my consideration.  Today, I was told that I'll be contacted again on Monday regarding my promotion.  By that wording, it seems to be a done deal.

Comment: thank you @SimonAndréForsberg.