# Must answers include a code review?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers

I'm surprised to ask this but, "Must answers include a Code Review?"

I'm looking at [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40565/34757).

- The request in the OP says,

  > Can you please look into my code and suggest me some performance improvement techniques?
- The answer says,

  > No, it doesn't work like that. ... you should start by profiling your execution ... Either way, first, profile the execution and identify the worst offenders."

Comment: I had flagged that answer as "not an answer" when I first came across it.

Answer (score 8):

In a word: Yes.

Although "Hey, use a profiler!" might be good advice, it's not on-topic or sufficient for this site. This site is for Code Reviews, and an answer on this site is not on-topic if it refuses to review the code.

Instead of being posted as an answer:

- It can be posted as a helpful comment to the question
- It can be a vote to close the question (if the question doesn't contain code which can be reviewed)

Another example is:

- [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40567/conways-game-of-life-speedups#comment68377_40567) I wanted to mention some links to other algorithms, but **I didn't want to review the OP code**: so I posted that as a comment, not an answer.
- [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40573/34757) I also posted a link to other algorithms, but **I also reviewed the code**: so I posted that as an answer.

My policy is similar to the one [in this meta-answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1485/34757) regarding answers which contain code, i.e. "Could this answer have been written by reading the text which describes the problem, without reading any of the code in the OP?"

- Yes, not one word of the answer relates to any word in the code of the OP -- therefore it's not a code review and is off-topic: "It was posted as an answer but does not attempt to answer the question (i.e. a request for a code review<sup>1</sup>). It should possibly be a comment ..."
- No, at least one word of the answer relates to the code (not just the description of the problem) -- therefore it's a **code** review and is on-topic.

<sup>1</sup><sub>We know the question must have been asking for a code review, otherwise the question wouldn't have been on-topic.</sub>

Comment: You convinced me. I made a minor edit and retracted my upvote (don't do this at home!).

Comment: What is your definition of a Code **Review**? Is [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40162/nesting-versus-goto-which-is-better-to-avoid/40179#40179) technically a Code Review? If so, in what way?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Why wouldn't you consider dead code elimination to be acceptable as code review?

Comment: @200_success I do believe the answer I linked to is a good answer, that is why I want to know how to define "Code Review".

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I did wonder about that answer at the time: I thought it would have been a great comment! One (strange) reason why it's *clearly* a Code Review is that the OP doesn't say (in English) that they're implementing a property-bag and property parser; so AJMansfield must have read the OP's code, and reverse-engineered its purpose, before suggesting the alternative: and that deserves credit. If the OP had started with "I'm implementing a 'Property' class using Java" then the answer would have been less impressive IMO, but an even better comment.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's always an adequate review to suggest equivalent pre-made functionality? If someone posts a question about a C++ circular buffer, can we point them to a [boost C++ library](http://www.boost.org/users/download/) class? And/or to a non-free vendor's offering? Does the answer depend on whether the OP is doing the code as an exercise, or for production? Is "[Is there a built-in API or third-party library which does this?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/225068/revisions)" a valid question, even though that might be seen as 'a shopping question'?

Comment: Also my worry about this specific answer was that just "Use a profiler!" might be used as an answer to any question about performance.

Comment: @ChrisW I don't like your "always" questions. I can't say anything about whether or not it's **always** an answer if you suggest equivalent pre-made functionality. The whole library-issues is an entirely different topic, but if they have re-invented the wheel without knowing it then I think suggesting that "This wheel already exists, here's how you use it yada-yada-yada..." is an OK answer.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Yes, "always" can imply a false dichotomy: "Is it always, or never?" I think I ask it in order to test the rule: is it true, and/or are there exceptions to the rule? I think that's a scientific method: "My hypothesis is that answers must contain a review to be on-topic. Is that always true, or is that contradicted by observed counter-examples?" It can be a way of generating useful laws, for example "Always Newtonian Mechanics, except when very fast or very massive or very small or...".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, answers must include a code review, but I'd like to point out that a [code review does not need to be long](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/9357).  Any concrete suggestion that would result in an improvement could constitute a review.