# Self-answers that re-write code with little/no explanation

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, self-answer

I came across this self-answer today:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10844/46800

It had no explanation or evaluation of the code in question, just a code rewrite.  This seems to me to not really achieve the purpose of this SE site in the first place, however it has been upvoted 3 times.  Are these answers acceptable?

... Just realised the original question is 2 years old.  My question still stands, though.

Comment: Related: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/short-answers-and-code-only-answers

Answer (score 12):

No, answers that just contain code are not acceptable, even if it is a self-answer. I have added a notice calling for an explanation.

Related posts:

- [For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/9357)
- [Short answers and code-only answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/9357)