# VLQ review queue, option for "this should be a comment"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, convert-to-comment

I was reviewing an item in the Low Quality queue (which I sadly cannot link to) that was most definitely not an answer and should have been a comment, because it was asking for clarification from the asker.

However, there did not appear to be an option to indicate such. It certainly wasn't ok to leave there, but it shouldn't be deleted either, it should instead have been migrated as a comment. I chose to skip it and hope that somebody with the correct privileges came along and moved it.

Should there be an option to recommend migrating an answer to a comment for those reviewing the VLQ queue who don't have sufficient privileges to do so themselves?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/29108

Comment: Recommend deletion usually does the trick well enough... if you're feeling lucky you can even choose the "this should be a comment" auto-comment..

Comment: @Pimgd it wasn't the one (it was reviewed about 10 mins ago), but it's a good example I guess.

Comment: @Vogel612, forgot about the auto-comments. Of course!

Comment: Sufficient privileges?  Only diamond moderators can convert answers to comments.

Comment: Which I would consider to be a privilege.

Comment: Moderators are mostly in charge of reviewing comments in general, which is why only they can see deleted ones.  If the community converts a bad answer into a bad comment (which can still happen), then it'll be harder to track it down.

Comment: Good point. Would an option then to simply flag it for conversion so a moderator can see it in some sort of "answers that should be comments" query be a good plan, or is it too seldom a situation to demand it?

Comment: Flagging such a thing for moderation attention is okay, especially if you need to specify further information to support your reasoning.

Comment: Can we do that from within the review queue? I couldn't see an option.

Comment: I don't think there is a way, though it has been a while since I have visited the queue.  Without moderator tools, you may have to recommend deletion and load the answer separately in order to flag it.  Otherwise, you can just flag the deleted answer.  But I think in most cases, if an answer has already been deleted by the community and/or a moderator, then it may not be worth undeleting and converting it to a comment.  This kind of conversion is *not* always a priority, and users with less than 50 rep shouldn't be encouraged to post answers as comments and having them converted.

Answer (score 4):

If the answer is worth keeping as a comment, flag it for moderator attention. Only moderators have the ability to convert an answer into a comment.

Otherwise, just press the <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> button.

Keep in mind, though, that any remark that points out a concrete fault with the code [should be an answer rather than a comment](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1479/9357), even if it is short.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to flag it from directly inside the queue. The only option is to recommend deletion. I believe the request is to get the option to flag it from inside the queue.