# Can I repost my question if the original received no answers or comments?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

The question I posted received no comment or answer at all. It was just edited by another person to make the wording better and clearer. I reviewed the question but I can't find any way to improve it.

Can I repost it exactly like the old question to see if anyone is interested?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot do this as it'll just be closed as a duplicate of the original question.  If you *really* have nothing else to do with the question nor do you have sufficient rep to raise a bounty, you may bring it up in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). If you do this, then you should *not* sound needy about it, but politely mention that you'd like someone to take a look at your old question.  After all, [we don't want anyone to get the Tumbleweed badge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/stack-exchange-data-explorer-is-up-what-now-wonderland/4947#4947).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind! Also, just a small question, if I update my question, does it get pushed to the top of the feed or not?

Comment: Yes, it always does.  But don't abuse this by making lots of trivial edits, otherwise it'll start to annoy others.

Comment: I'll try to find a way to improve my question. Thanks a lot!