# Tool for Zombie-hunting

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

A couple of weeks ago there was a discussion in The 2nd Monitor about reducing [Zombies](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1511/120114) and bringing the answered percentage up.

I've noticed during my searches of unanswered questions that some of the answers actually have answers that haven't been voted up. I'd like to be able to do a search for all unanswered questions that actually have answers to see if I can improve the answer rate for voting on some of the answers.

Is there documentation on how to search the database, and a scheme for the database? I looked at the Code Review help page and there is nothing there. I've also searched Meta Code Review.

I see this as a feature request for the Meta Code Review, not the regular Code Review.

@EBrown has shown some statistics on The 2nd Monitor. I was also wondering if these could be posted as tools to Meta that require some reputation to see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've noticed during my searches of unanswered questions that some of the answers actually have answers that haven't been voted up.

This is what I call ["Ripe Zombies"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/stack-exchange-data-explorer-is-up-what-now-wonderland/4970#4970) (ripe as in ready for the shooting),
and [@RoboSanta](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75639/robosanta?tab=profile) posts 2 such questions per day in The 2nd Monitor that match this criteria,
in the hope of attracting the attention of zombie killers.
The questions are randomly selected from the results of [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/412155/ripe-zombies) (which is linked from the Ripe Zombies post too).

Another, crude way to find such questions is apparently to go the [Unanswered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) filter of the site or your favorite tag, and jump to the last page. There tend to be many questions with answers on the last few pages.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The crude way is how I found out about this. I've been closing some Ripe Zombies this way.

Comment: What does shooting mean? downvoting and deleting? Or upvoting?