# The CRonicles: Story of a Stack

Tags: discussion, beta-progress, chat, meta

Something pretty cool was born earlier today. There was a [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/conversation/cr-chronicles) involving new reviewers reviewees, about the site's graduation and the History of Code Review.

> Mat's Mug: *people can read the whole story by following the* [beta-progress](/questions/tagged/beta-progress) *tag's timeline on meta, starting with [this one](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/991).*

The discussion had been dragging for a little while, some regulars were being a bit annoyed:

> Vogel612: *@Mat'sMug you really want to go through it all over?*
>
> Quill: *either that, or take this to nth*

<sub>Context: *The N<sup>th</sup> Monitor* is where not quite on-topic conversations are to be had.</sub>

> Zak: *I also wouldn't mind a walk-through by people who went through it. I've pieced together most of it but never had it gone through all in one go.*

So I went and created a new chatroom: *CR Chronicles* [(transcript)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/27598/2015/8/31).

> *About CR's revival, The Mission, zombies, graduation, etc.*

---

Did I just feel like writing? I don't know. But I always wanted to say this:

> Mat's Mug: *ok kids, sit in a circle, uncle Mug is going to tell a story*

What followed was a narrative of the story behind this graph:

[image: Site activity graph, 2011-2015]

The story was told, the transcript will keep these meta-links together in one place and in context... but the story is still being written as I type these words, and as you read this post.

---

SE Chat chatrooms eventually freeze, and if nobody unfreezes them, the system eventually deletes them.

> rolfl: *I think this sort of officially means we are also the first beta site to get a history-channel.*

What should we do with this chatroom?

Comment: Funny how this question is posted without a link to the [actual chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27598/the-cronicles)...

Answer (score 13):

#### Continue the story!

We proved it, *many things* can happen in a relatively short period of time. Let's first rename this chatroom to **The CRonicles**, and then use it to conceal various meta-things:

- Links to noteworthy posts for the annual "Best-of" meta-party, using `[tag:best-of-2015]` for easy searching of the transcript.
- Links to [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and [beta-progress](/questions/tagged/beta-progress) questions (using a RSS feed to not miss anything!).
- Links to bookmarked, noteworthy conversations in The 2nd Monitor.

But also, it makes a place for questions/discussions *about CR's revival, The Mission, zombies, graduation, etc.* to happen, without having to point newcomers "to meta" into a sea of meta Q&A's and no one to guide them. This isn't just [meta](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) - it's [meta-meta](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-meta). It's not a place to discuss the site rules and scope; it's a place to "bookmark" a spot in the timeline to link to the meta post that resulted in a change to site rules/scope. Notice the nuance?

Comment: This. We are still not graduated so our story is far from over. Having a chat room dedicated to our history may be beneficial in the long run.